# Pass a custom formula into a query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to pass a string into a query formula

Ex : Instead of writing in a cell the normal syntax

```
=query (Sheet!A5:B;"Select A where B = 15";)
```

I would like to put this as *Sheet* refers to the name of the sheet in another cell (C5 --> see formula below)

```
QUERY(C5&"!A5:B;" & CHAR (34) &"Select A where B=15" & CHAR (34);)
```

I don't know why it doesn't work... But when i do this, i only get this as result :

```
Sheet!A5:B;"Select A where B = 15"
```

Can someone explain me please how to fix that issue. I don't know why the query didn't execute.

Comment: Excel doesn't have the QUERY formula. Hence I've removed all references to it. Please only use appropriate tags.

Comment: You will need to use INDIRECT: `=query (INDIRECT(C5&"!A5:B");"Select A where B = 15";)`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY({INDIRECT(C5&"!A5:B")};
 "select Col1 where Col2 = 15"; )
```